# Error in AJAX 'POST' call fetching API from PHP file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to fetch some information into my HTML file using an AJAX post request by using JQuery connected to a PHP file. I am attempting two post requests and one get request, the latter works but there seems to be errors with the post request and I do not know whether I am doing wrong the AJAX calls or if it is my PHP file.

PHP:

// earthquakes.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

var_dump($_REQUEST['North']);

$url =
    'http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?formatted=true&north=' .
    $_REQUEST['North'] .
    '&south=' .
    $_REQUEST['South'] .
    '&east=' .
    $_REQUEST['East'] .
    '&west=' .
    $_REQUEST['West'] .
    '&username=kyleghilotti&style=full';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
//$encode = json_encode($data);
$decode = json_decode($data, true);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

?>
```

// api.php

```
<?php

var_dump($_REQUEST);

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url =
    'http://api.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=' .
    $_REQUEST['North'] .
    '&south=' .
    $_REQUEST['South'] .
    '&east=' .
    $_REQUEST['East'] .
    '&west=' .
    $_REQUEST['West'] .
    '&username=kyleghilotti';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
//$encode = json_encode($data);
$decode = json_decode($data, true);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

?>
```

// PHP file containing the api used for the get request omitted....

// JS (JQuery)

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    if ($('#preloader').length) { $('#preloader').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); }); }
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#coordinates').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            url: "../task/php/api.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                North: $('#North').val(),
                South: $('#South').val(),
                East: $('#East').val(),
                West: $('#West').val(),
            },
            success: function (result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result) {
                    $('#clouds').html(result['data'][0]['clouds']);
                    $('#temperature').html(result['data'][0]['temperature']);
                    $('#station').html(result['data'][0]['stationname']);


                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
            }
        });

    });


    $('#countries').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../task/php/country.php",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result) {
                    $('#languages').html(result.languages);
                    $('#distance').html(result.distance);
                    $('#countryCode').html(result.countryName);


                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
            }
        });

    });


    $('#earthquakes').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "../task/php/earthquakes.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                North: $('#N').val(),
                South: $('#S').val(),
                East: $('#E').val(),
                West: $('#W').val(),
            },
            success: function (result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result) {
                    $('#depth').html(result.depth);
                    $('#lng').html(result.lng);
                    $('#magnitude').html(result.magnitude);
                    $('#lat').html(result.lat);


                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
            }
        });

    });

});
```

// Frontend - HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/index.css">
    <title>Task | GeoNames</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="preloader"></div>

    <h1>Weather coordinates</h1>

    <form method="POST">
        <label for="North">North</label>
        <input name="North" type="number" step="0.01" id="North"/>
        <label for="South">South</label>
        <input name="South" type="number" step="0.01" id="South"/>
        <label for="East">East</label>
        <input name="East" type="number" step="0.01" id="East"/>
        <label for="West">West</label>
        <input name="West" type="number" step="0.01" id="West"/>
        <input type="submit" id="coordinates" />
    </form>

    <h1>Earthquake coordinates</h1>

    <form method="POST">
        <label for="North">North</label>
        <input name="North" type="number" step="0.01" id="N"/>
        <label for="South">South</label>
        <input name="South" type="number" step="0.01" id="S"/>
        <label for="East">East</label>
        <input name="East" type="number" step="0.01" id="E"/>
        <label for="West">West</label>
        <input name="West" type="number" step="0.01" id="W"/>
        <input type="submit" id="earthquakes" />
    </form>
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>API Name</td>
            <td>API Description</td>
            <td>Go</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Weather By coordinates</td>
            <td>Weather</td>
            <td><button>Submit</button></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Get countries</td>
            <td>All countries</td>
            <td><button id="countries">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Earthquakes</td>
            <td>Earthquakes by longitude and latitude</td>
            <td><button>Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <span id="clouds"></span>
        <span id="temperature"></span>
        <span id="station"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span id="languages"></span>
        <span id="distance"></span>
        <span id="countryCode"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span id="depth"></span>
        <span id="lng"></span>
        <span id="magnitude"></span>
        <span id="lat"></span>
    </div>


    <script type="application/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: having `var_dump` or any spurious text output in the php will invalidate any JSON output

Comment: even by removing the var_dump(s) it is still outputting errors: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Use your browser's Devtools/Network tab to view requests and responses

Comment: Does `api.php` actually return something? You have `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');` there but are not outputting/returning anything

Comment: @brombeer it looks as if there is no response sent back for api.php when opening the network tab and for earthquake.php call I got the error mentioned above.

Comment: The response from the geonames endoints should be json so just echo that response. Not knowing suitable values makes it hard to test as I get `missing or invalid parameter for south/north/east/west` when testing

Comment: ah.... your form elements and AJAX parameters are all capitalised first letter - these must be lowercase

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius that is what it printed: "{"status":{"message":"missing or invalid parameter for south/north/east/west","value":14}}", however these values should be in my $_REQUEST array

Comment: I used lowercase for `North`, `South` etc and it works fine (admittedly slightly different code ) but and example of the full url used `http://api.geonames.org/weatherJSON?formatted=1&username=kyleghilotti&style=full&north=2.75&south=35.45&east=85.2&west=0.54` is OK - if this had `North` etc it would fail

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i tried to put all the parameters in lowercase but it still gives me the same error: {"status": {
  "message": "missing or invalid parameter for south/north/east/west",
  "value": 14
}}

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius would you mind to share the code you used ? i tried to set all parameters across the HTML, PHP and JS files in lowercase as well as named the ids and name fields in the same name just in case but it is still throwing me the same errors....

Comment: OK: The code I have is a little( ok, a lot ) different but it is all in a single PHP page/script - you can run this `as-is` to see the basics results and formatting in javascript... hope it helps. [The full example](https://pastebin.com/khTCbuMw) - edit the username to suit!

Comment: in the pastebin code there is a spurious `sa` towards the end of the `curl` function... nfi how that got there but should be removed